# Como insertar nombre de usuario en wordpres con un plugin

Tags: wordpress

estoy tratando de modificar un plugin, le agregue un campo mas que se llama user_name, El plguin consiste en contar la cantidad de visitantes de la pagina y quien la visito mediante la ip.. yo lo que quiero es que me grabe el nombre de usuario en la tabla pero no lo consigo.
este es el codigo

```
if ( ! $this->result ) {
        //aqui agarro el nombre de usuario logueado
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $usuario = $user->user_login;
        $wpdb->insert(
            $wpdb->prefix . "statistics_visitor",
            array(
                'last_counter' => $this->Current_date( 'Y-m-d' ),
                'referred'     => $this->get_Referred(),
                'agent'        => $this->agent['browser'],
                'platform'     => $this->agent['platform'],
                'version'      => $this->agent['version'],
                'ip'           => $this->get_IP(),
                'location'     => '000',
                //aqui es donde lo trato de insertar
                'user_name'    => $usuario,
            )
        );
    }
```

Alguna ayuda de que estoy haciendo mal?.. el plugin se llama Wp-Statistic

Comment: ¿Creaste el campo "user_name" dentro de la Data Base y en la tabla donde estás tratando de hacer el insert? Con ese pequeño trozo de código no te puedo decir mucho más. También he visto que detrás de "'user_name'    => $usuario" te sobra la coma, ya que es el último elemento del array y la coma indica que se está esperando otro elemento.

Comment: Si cree el campo en la base de datos, solo subi un esta parte del codigo porque es muy largo y solo en esa parte estoy modificando

Comment: si `$user->ID = 0` no hay nadie logueado

Comment: $user->ID = 0 como seria esto? no entiendo

Comment: `$user = wp_get_current_user();` carga un objeto tipo WP_User si hay alguien logueado tiene la info dentro, en caso de que no identifique un usuario logueado el ID es 0, proba hacer un `var_dump($user);die();` justo antes del insert a ver si está leyendo bien el usuario logueado

Comment: ahh.. si ya hice eso y esta detectando bien

Comment: mepa que la modificacion va en [`public function Add_user()`](https://github.com/wp-statistics/wp-statistics/blob/45c09ebfa5faa476fcdde03ffa64dcaccd99822d/includes/classes/class-wp-statistics-hits.php#L653) salvo que sea otra versión del plugin

Comment: Podrias explicarme mejor?

Comment: estuve mirando la funcion Add_user(), pero el agrega en una tabla llamada statistics_useronline, y yo necesito que guarde en una tabla llamada statistics_visitor, podrias explicarme mejor ?

Comment: =P la verdad no, ví el source en github y busqué donde guarda la visita (con un hash_ip que trae de un "user" si es que existe y que en un punto agrega) pero no vi mas alla de ahí. fijate si es el mismo código tal vez tengas la versión del svn de worpress y sea diferente =)

Comment: parece estar activo el repo, si posteas un issue? https://github.com/wp-statistics/wp-statistics/issues

Comment: voy a mirar.. gracias